# RavenDB Transformer cannot map to Integer Id

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am using a transformer to map to a view model, but I'm running into a problem where I cannot map the Raven Id to my model integer Id. Is this because RavenDB uses strings for Id's and How can I get round this?

> Raven.Imports.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not read value for property: Id ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
public class Model_ViewModel : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<Model>
{
    public Model_ViewModel()
    {
        TransformResults = models => models
            .Select(m => new Model
            {
                Id = m.Id, // This is causing an error
                Name = m.Name,
                Age = m.Age
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of ids on ravendb are actually strings.
The server is sending the full document name, and you are trying to parse that into an integer.
Try changing the client side type to a string.